# Update config file contents with output from Active Directory query

Tags: xml, powershell

Powershell noob here! I need some assistance with replacing values within my config file to match the value of an user extension attribute within Active Directory.

**Here is what I have:**

$XML = "C:\Users\Test.User04\Documents\test.config"

$Variable = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -prop othertelephone -Server generic.com.au | select @{n="othertelephone";e={$_.othertelephone -join ";"}}

(Get-Content $XML | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '10586',"$Variable"} | 
Set-Content C:\Users\Test.User04\Documents\test2.config)

**Issues:**

1. Query from AD extension attribute is providing name and value, when I only need the value
2. How to pinpoint specific location within config file (red box in screenshot) that requires replacement with extension attribute value only.

As you can see the current limitation of the above code is that I have to manually specify the value within the config file which in this example is '10586'. What I want to do is to always replace the value within the config file regardless of what the number is.
[Screenshot of config file with red box around value requiring replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ovFf.png)

Comment: [1] why are you NOT converting the loaded XML text into an XML _object_? that would allow you to access & modify the various items as props and then export the result as an XML text file. [2] since you posted a _picture_ of the XML file, no one can use that data for testing code. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: I will look into the XML object. I am new to this site and noticed that you are not able to attach files. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: yep ... you cannot attach files. if you need to work with one that is too large to paste into the Question, then you will likely need to prune the file down to a workable size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) is right and you should not use regex replacements on xml files. PowerShell makes it very easy to deal with xml.

As you did not provide a representative **textual** xml example, this is untested:

```
$xmlOut   = 'C:\Users\Test.User04\Documents\test2.config'
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Test.User04\Documents\test.config' -Raw

# $Variable will be an object with one property 'otherTelephone'
$Variable = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties otherTelephone -Server 'generic.com.au' | 
            Select-Object @{Name = "otherTelephone"; Expression = {$_.otherTelephone -join ";"}}

# find the node for which you need to replace the 'user' attribute
$userNode = $xml.SipEndpoint.Container.Connectivity | Where-Object { $_.user -eq '10586' }

# if found, replace the attribute with the 'otherTelephone' property in $Variable
if ($userNode) { $userNode.SetAttribute('user', $Variable.otherTelephone) }

# save the updated xml as new file
$xml.Save($xmlOut)
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH Theo and Lee. The above script resolves my first issue and it updates just the required value!

I have a work around for my second issue.

Appreciate your profound knowledge and assistance :) I have been playing around with the XML object and now have a better understanding.